# How to solve this inequality with Reduce or Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I need to solve this inequality:

```
Reduce[-(1/(lamda*beta*(1 - d)))*
    Log[(delta - beta (1 - 2 d))/(lamda*delta)] < d && 0 < lamda < 1 &&
   0 < beta < 1 && 0 < delta < beta/(1 - lamda) && 
  Max[(beta - delta)/(2 beta); 0] < 
   d < (beta - delta + lamda*delta)/(2*beta), d, Reals]
```

But Reduce doesn't work for this..neither does solve
("This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.'')

One can analytically show that there exists a d_0 in ] Max[(beta - delta)/(2 beta); 0] ; beta - delta + lamda*delta)/(2*beta)[ such that:

-(1/(lamda* beta*(1 - d)))*
Log[(delta - beta (1 - 2 d))/(lamda *delta)] < d on ]d_0; beta - delta + lamda *delta)/(2*beta)[.

and

-(1/(lamda* beta*(1 - d)))*
Log[(delta - beta (1 - 2 d))/(lamda *delta)] > d on ] Max[(beta - delta)/(2 beta); 0] ; d_0[.

But,
What i actually want to understand is why neither Reduce or Solve works for this kind of problem ?

Comment: These two functions work fine on polynomial equations or inequalities. The transcendental ones they only solve in some (most simple) cases. Your inequalities does not belong to such solvable cases.

Comment: THanks ! Is there a way in mathematica  to solve this type of equations ?

Comment: Sometimes, if you are lucky you can find a replacement that will transform the expressions into solvable ones. In some cases, you might succeed to pass to dimensionless variables, thus, decreasing the number of parameters, and then solve them numerically.